# c# forms application displaying even if user loggs off or locks computer

Tags: c#, winforms, background

I'm writing an application that'll display a lightweight dashboard to the computer's secondary display (displaying permits that'll expire within X days and suchlike).
It will be running on a secretary's Windows XP computer with 2 graphics cards.  One for the secretary's monitor and another for the flatscreen that's facing the reception area.

Ideally i'd have the flatscreen controlled by a dedicated machine rather than have a user operating on it doing what users to best (Try explaining that to procurement).

So the app's displaying to the secondary screen without a problem and hidden from the taskbar.

```
this.Location = secondDisplay.WorkingArea.Location;
```

The problem is it needs to run and display even if no one is logged in.

Is there any way i can have the app run in the background and display to the screen even if a user is logged off or locks the machine?

Comment: Thanks, all

I'm considering the issue closed.  I knew the chances were pretty much nil to solve this programically (the real solution is in hardware).

My aim was to get the 'opinion of the scientific community';  ammunition to say "get me a workstation" to those in charge.

Comment: Kinda wish i could mark both Marciej and Brad's answers as 'accepted answer'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display machine wouldn't need to be very powerful at all.  An older system could be used (green points for not putting it in the landfill).

If there's not an old computer laying around, something like a mini-itx system or even a netbook with a port for an external monitor (I don't think all netbooks have them) would work well.

If they're dropping the dime to allow for development and a display panel, an inexpensive machine shouldn't strain the budget.  Now if you really want to impress, show them this [VGA splitter](http://www.national-tech.com/specs/svga-spliter/41h1-14814.htm).  With this you could display the same information throughout the office as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not worth reinventing the wheel?

I would recommend use additional PC. Connect it to LAN 
Than use one of free screen sharing software:
To cut cost you can use eg [UltraVnc](http://www.uvnc.com/) + Linux as OS

Than you can display same screen on this PC

Answer (score 1):

If you can convince them to upgrade to Vista or Windows 7 instead of XP, you should take a look at the [Windows SideShow](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/features/sideshow.aspx) technology. From the website:

> Windows SideShow is a new technology
>   that delivers information from your PC
>   to a secondary display on two kinds of
>   devices: those that are integrated
>   into a computer, such as a small color
>   display in a laptop lid; and those
>   that are separate from a computer,
>   such as a remote control or mobile
>   phone. With this additional display
>   you can view important information
>   whether your laptop is on, off, or in
>   sleep mode.

You can get information on SideShow capable devices [here](http://www.sideshowdevices.com/) and [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=42F2F862-9987-406C-92A3-6523CF0EB3B3&displaylang=en) a managed SDK as well.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your scenario  is doable, your one or two extra days to get it done will cost more than a cheap computer that will do the job right.